# Inverting a function that involves the norm

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers, normed-spaces

Let $j \in \mathbb{C}^2,\ j_1 \in \mathbb{R}, \ \phi_i \in \mathbb{C}^{2\times2}$, with $det(\phi_i)\neq 0$ and $\phi_i \neq \phi_j, i \neq j, \ i,j\in {1,2,3}$.

Furthermore the following holds $$||j||^2 = \sum_{i=0}^{s}||\phi_i(j)||^2 $$

Is it then possible to reobtain $j$, if I just have all $||\phi_i(j)||^2$?

If not, what extra conditons must hold for the matrices?